# Goobspatch flagged as malicious by MacOS. What should I do?

Tags: macos, malware, virus

My Mac just popped up this warning:

> "goobspatch" can't be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.
> This software needs to be updated.
> Contact the developer for more information.
> This item is on the disk image
> "com.google.Chrome.dmg". Chrome downloaded this disk image on an unknown date.”

When I clicked on “Show in Finder”, it showed the root directory with no sign of the file.

My wifi has been dodgy for the last few hours but only on this computer. Is this related, and what are the best steps to take to remedy the situation?

It’s an M1 MacBook Air running MacOS v13.4.1

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/apple-cant-check-app-for-malicious-software-mchleab3a043/mac

Comment: Why exactly do you want to open/install an [app that appears to be malicious](https://www.bing.com/search?q=what+is+goobspatch&cvid=35058b1d5f6e41f284493180f739b1d1&aqs=edge.1.69i57j0l2.8676j0j4&FORM=ANAB01&PC=U531)

Comment: Dear Allan, that is of course not what I want to do. I want to locate it and remove it safely. I have followed the directions on that Apple page, but that is about enabling an unsigned application. My issue is that the system flagged malware and I want to know what to do about it.

Comment: @Allan has shown you a bing search about goobspatch which includes links on to how to remove it. Have you tried any of those?

Comment: I deleted Chrome entirely, installed Malware Bytes (demo version). It found no malware, so I checked MacOS was up to date, rebooted the system, then reinstalled Chrome. So far so good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning message provides you with all the information you need. Firstly:

> "Apple cannot check it for malicious software. This software needs to
> be updated."

It has not been flagged as malicious: but it could not be checked. Consequently, it was prevented from running. (However, Goobspatch is indeed malware, which inserts its own adverts into websites that you view.)

The software is on a mounted disk image: you have not installed it to your Macintosh HD volume. Unmount the disk image from your Desktop; and delete the .dmg file (probably in Downloads).

Also, people don't write malware that makes your wifi signal dodgy. Malware is usually designed to do things without your knowing: like serving you adverts; scoop up personal data; send out spam email; etc.

Comment: Goobspatch is malware, I assume the OP doesn't want to install any version at all.

Comment: @nohillside Useful safety tip!